# where to call super methods

Tags: ios

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{


   self.listArr=nil;
   self.tableView1=nil;

   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
```

i should put the [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]  at the last or front，or not write.can you give some detail explain?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for this method? It clearly state that you need to call super at some point. Putting it first is probably best, but I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a call to the superclass inside of many methods in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955317/why-is-there-a-call-to-the-superclass-inside-of-many-methods-in-objective-c)

Comment: It is better to be the last line when you are releasing the params(Remember the dealloc method). As per [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning), you just have to call at some point.